# 403 on Google Action push notification request

Tags: jwt, actions-on-google

I'm trying to perform a push notification for Google Actions Intent.

Thus far, I've followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications#send_notifications

This is my resulting code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
var request = require('request');

const key = require('./bot.json');

module.exports = async function (context, myQueueItem) {
    context.log('JavaScript queue trigger function processed work item', myQueueItem);

    let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email, null, key.private_key,
       ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
        null
      );

      jwtClient.authorize((err, tokens) => {
        // code to retrieve target userId and intent
        let notif = {
          userNotification: {
            title: [message],
          },
          target: {
              userId:[obtained from permission request],
              intent: [name of intent],
            // Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
            locale: 'en-US'
          },
        };

        request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
          'auth': {
            'bearer': tokens.access_token,
           },
          'json': true,
          'body': {'customPushMessage': notif},
        }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
            console.log(body);
           console.log(httpResponse.statusCode + ': ' + httpResponse.statusMessage);
        });
      });
};

//module.exports(console, "Test");
```

This results in a 403 from the notification service. Is this because of the user id, intent name or jwtoken that was generated?

Comment: Have you enabled **Would you like to send push notifications** in User Engagement for your intent in your Actions Console ?

Comment: Yep, I had enabled it in User Engagement.

Comment: do you get a 403 all the time? there is a 1 notifications per user per minute limit when sending notifications. do you get any error messages?

Comment: yep. 100% failures

Comment: Have you enabled the Actions API for your project?

Go to the [Google Cloud Platform console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/actions.googleapis.com/overview) to activate the Actions API, and select the project that you have created on the Actions on Google console. Then, click the Enable button.

Comment: Hi @TaylorCaldwell, yep, did that too: https://imgur.com/a/yLIdK2X

Comment: I have same issue: statusCode":403,"body":{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}

Comment: Hey folks, I just confirmed that the feature works with a 200. A couple things I'd check:
1) You're using the same intent in your request as the one you used when requesting permission to send push notifications
2) You are using a key associated with an owner-level service account in your GCP project
Otherwise your code looks good

Comment: While sending notification i got this error   
(node:22520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_to
ken' of undefined

Answer (score -1):

Following are the steps we need to check before sending the push notification

1. **Check your Google permission settings**
   In order to test the Action, you need to enable the necessary permissions.

Go to the ‘**Activity Controls**' page (https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols).
Sign in with your Google account, if you have not already done so.
Ensure that the following permissions are enabled:

```
a.Web & App Activity
b.Device Information
c.Voice & Audio Activity
```

2.**Target intent** name should be added into the **Implicit invocation** field.
with enabled push notification.
3.use the same email id in your google assistant which you had used for login in **GCP**.